# Headers getting ignored for fetch POST API in react using Isomarpic-fetch

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch, credentials, isomorphic-fetch-api

Backend Server : Implemented google authentication using spring OAuth 2

So with the above details, i am trying to hit an api endpoint as below,

```
 fetch(`http://localhost:8080/users`,
    {
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        method : 'POST',
        body : JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.status
    })
```

this gives me a status code 302 and the headers are never set as a part of request headers. In addition to this, the cookies are never set.

I've wasted 2 full days to understand why the headers are not being set and have gone through many posts on SO and github, none of us have helped me.

So any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

finally being able to find a way to work my POST API.

I am running both front-end and back-end server locally but running on different ports. but chrome or Firefox won't support to include headers in this case.

Need to run in web security in disable mode 
ubuntu machine:
google-chrome  --user-data-dir=”/var/tmp/Chrome” --disable-web-security